# I need to get the total number of the opportunities depending on the picklist value selected

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, dynamic-visualforce

I want to create a field in accounts object that will display the total number of opportunities depending on the picklist value selected. What approach should I use to achieve this? As much as possible I want to avoid triggers. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Rollup summary field on Account object and provide the criteria. Something like this image:

[image]